# Limiting a specific shell's internet bandwidth usage

Tags: networking, process, bandwidth, limit

I want update my linux in one shell but by default wget or axel in updater use all the bandwidth.

How can I limit the speed in this shell?

I want other shells to have a fair share, and to limit everything in that shell – something like a proxy!

I use Zsh and Arch Linux.

This question focuses on process-wide or session-wide solutions. See [How to limit network bandwidth?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28198/how-to-limit-network-bandwidth) for system-wide or container-wide solutions on Linux.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have a look at [trickle](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Trickle) a userspace bandwidth shaper. Just start your shell with trickle and specify the speed, e.g.:

```
trickle -d 100 zsh
```

which tries to limit the download speed to 100KB/s for all programs launched inside this shell.

As trickle uses `LD_PRELOAD` this won't work with static linked programs but this isn't a problem for most programs.

Comment: Note that it's limited to SOCK_STREAMS sockets, so won't affect UDP traffic for instance.

Answer (score 5):

http://lartc.org/wondershaper/

It is in Ubuntu / Debian repositories, probably others too. It limits not just a single shell, but the whole machine. Never tried it myself though

Answer (score 2):

The [man page for `wget`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) provides the following information:

```
 --limit-rate=amount
```

> Limit the download speed to amount bytes per second.  Amount may be
>   expressed in bytes, kilobytes with the k    suffix, or megabytes with
>   the m suffix.  For example, --limit-rate=20k will limit the retrieval
>   rate to 20KB/s.    This is useful when, for whatever reason, you don't
>   want Wget to consume the entire available bandwidth.

Comment: update question: i want all application limited, not only wget

Comment: @Efazati: Sorry I don't know how to set it in general. I use it only for wget and apt-get.

Comment: don't wory man, just wating for answer ;)