# Artificially induces slow network traffic for single program

Tags: networking, python, testing

I need to test that a given (python) application works properly when the network is slow. Is there a way to simulate this on a local machine? Ideally it would be possible to do this for a single application, without making admin-required modifications to the system. eg a packet dropping proxy server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting a specific shell's internet bandwidth usage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39384/limiting-a-specific-shells-internet-bandwidth-usage)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39384/limiting-a-specific-shells-internet-bandwidth-usage covers this if by “slow” you mean low-bandwidth. If you want latency, I'm not sure if the tools mentioned in the answers can do it; if the older question doesn't help you, please edit your question to make it more specific.

Comment: what kind of program is that? a simple `LD_PRELOAD` hack which intercepts the `read`, `recv`, etc. calls and sleeps before returning the data may do. Otherwise, I may be mistaken, but I don't think you're be able to do that without privileges and/or virtualization.

Comment: @mosvy The program is a python script. I tested trickle out with python (using youtube-dl) but it didn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: @Paul, `trickle` works for me with `youtube-dl`. What system are you on?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I am using Ubuntu 19.10, Python 3.7. An example trickle command I tried is "trickle -d 5 youtube-dl URL"

Comment: @Paul, indeed, I find trickle or tsocks works with python2.7, but not with python3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04. dante's socksify with my approach works though. Must be down to which network functions python3 uses and that those tools hijack or not.

Answer (score 1):

Beside [`trickle`](/a/39393), a possible hacky way that also has the benefit of giving some live status of the "speed" of throttled *connection* and lets you share the throttled *connection* between independent applications:

```
ssh -D 1080 -N -o ProxyCommand='
    pv -B8K -trabcN OUT -L2K |
    socat - tcp:%h:%p,rcvbuf=8K |
    pv -B8K -trabcN  IN -L30K' localhost
```

To launch a SOCKS5 server that is throttled because of the proxy command that is slowed down by `pv`'s rate limiting (`-L`), here throttling output and input at different rates.

And then socksify your command with `tsocks` for instance configured with a `~/.tsocks.conf` like:

```
server = 127.0.0.1
server_port = 1080
server_type = 5
```

Downloading some iso image without `tsocks`:

```
$ wget -O /dev/null http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.10/ubuntu-18.10-live-server-amd64.iso
/dev/null             2%[                    ]  19.60M  1.99MB/s    eta 6m 47s
```

the same socksified:

```
$ tsocks wget -O /dev/null http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.10/ubuntu-18.10-live-server-amd64.iso
/dev/null             0%[                    ] 802.40K  29.3KB/s    eta 3h 21m
```

Meanwhile, the `pv` output looks like:

```
      OUT: 3.65KiB 0:00:32 [0.00 B/s] [ 116 B/s]
       IN:  960KiB 0:00:32 [30.5KiB/s] [30.0KiB/s]
```

(shows both current speed (`-r`) and average (`-a`)).

`tsocks` or other socksifying commands inject code in executables (using `$LD_PRELOAD`) to hijack their networking functions so they go through the SOCKS server. That won't work for commands that are statically linked or are setuid/setgid...

Also note that `tsocks` only does TCP. I believe ssh's SOCKS server also only does TCP, so even if you switched to another socksifier like `dante`'s, you would still not be able to throttle UDP traffic that way. You could try and devise a similar approach using dante's SOCKS server instead of `ssh` though.

**edit**. When it comes to python3, I find that neither `trickle` nor `tsocks` manage to divert python3's networking (testing with `youtube-dl`). `dante`'s `socksify` seems to work though. To use it, create a `~/.dante.conf` like:

```
route {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0   to: 0.0.0.0/0   via: 127.0.0.1 port = 1080
}
```

And call your application as:

```
SOCKS_CONF=~/.dante.conf socksify youtube-dl https://...
```