# How to control network bandwidth using Linux

Tags: linux, networking, terminal, linux-mint

Currently my Internet is really slow. But I want to allocate all resources to a browser that is loading a movie. How do I do that?

Comment: upvote this please!! :)

Comment: If you want upvotes, ask a better question. Begging won't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to set all the resources to a particular IP address, you can achieve it using `tc` command. But is it worth spending the time on it, it's upto you. :)

From man page of [tc](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tc) command,

> **Description**
>
> Tc is used to configure Traffic Control in the Linux kernel. Traffic
> Control consists of the following:
>
> **SHAPING** When traffic is shaped, its rate of transmission is under
> control. Shaping may be more than lowering the available bandwidth -
> it is also used to smooth out bursts in traffic for better network
> behaviour. Shaping occurs on egress.
>
> **SCHEDULING** By scheduling the
> transmission of packets it is possible to improve interactivity for
> traffic that needs it while still guaranteeing bandwidth to bulk
> transfers. Reordering is also called prioritizing, and happens only on
> egress.
>
> **POLICING** Where shaping deals with transmission of traffic,
> policing pertains to traffic arriving. Policing thus occurs on
> ingress.
>
> **DROPPING** Traffic exceeding a set bandwidth may also be
> dropped forthwith, both on ingress and on egress. Processing of
> traffic is controlled by three kinds of objects: qdiscs, classes and
> filters.

Some interesting links which give a way to use this command,

https://serverfault.com/questions/191560/how-can-i-do-traffic-shaping-in-linux-by-ip

[How to limit network bandwidth?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28198/how-to-limit-network-bandwidth)

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-traffic-shaping-using-tc-to-control-http-traffic/